# Can I create a Brokerage account on my own company's name?

Tags: limited-liability-company

I own an LLC ( 2 member) in US. Can I have a brokerage account under its name? If yes the income/loss/ expenses associated with the account can be part of the LLC financials? Will the brokerage company provide me with annual Tax statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, to all.

I have two LLCs, and each one has a brokerage account.  In my case, I wanted regular checking accounts and not brokerage accounts, but for some reason, Fidelity lets businesses open only brokerage accounts.

I use these brokerage accounts as checking accounts but I could trade in them if I wanted to.